# Uso de DataAnnotations em projetos DDD

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ddd

Estamos com uma duvida que analista levantou, quando uso DataAnnotations na ViewModel em projetos que usam DDD no caso tem uma camada de Domínio e no caso não vai expandir, esse uso eliminaria a camada de domino por está duplicando a validação de campo, por exemplo:

Estou validando se o e-mail foi preenchido neste caso precisaria fazer novamente essa validação no domínio?

Comment: Eu não saberia dizer até porque não conheço bem DDD. E porque não acho uma boa metodologia na maioria dos casos. Eu diria que depende :) Essa ideia que o domínio é tão estático assim me desagrada. As coisas são cheias de contextos. Por eu adotar uma estratégia muito diferente eu não posso ajudar muito mais, mas fica a dica que as coisas podem se tornar mais complexos que o DDD dá conta, que por sinal já adiciona complexidade para a aplicação só por causa do mecanismo e não por causa do domínio, o que é uma ironia :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Estou validando se o e-mail foi preenchido neste caso precisaria fazer novamente essa validação no domínio?

R.:Sim, a validação que você usa na viewmodel é para ser utilizada pela validação no cliente (apesar de validar no servidor também com model.isvalid). Você não deve usar a entidade do negócio como ViewModel. Use sempre uma viewmodel para transferir apenas os dados necessários a serem exibidos na view. Para preencher automaticamente a viewmodel utilize o Automapper e para fazer as regras de validação da entidade utilize o FluentValidation.

Comment: Porque usar FluentValidation?

Comment: Separa melhor as responsabilidades das classes, aumentando a coesão e fazendo seu código mais legível, já que você coloca toda a parte de validação separada.

Comment: Mas pelo que entendi, não é recomendado usar Model ou Entidade de negócio, o problema que muitas vezes ambas são iguais, não deveriam ser?

Comment: No caso de cadastros básicos a view model será igual a Entidade do negócio. Eu uso a mesma nesses casos mas já li pessoas defendendo não usar nem nesses casos.

Comment: Queria muito descobrir os motivos, pq deve ter, tipo ataque algo assim seria super interessante alguém postar os motivos do não uso ViewModel como sendo regra de negócio, para até ajudar quem tem essa dúvida como eu e meu amigos de trabalho.

Comment: Os motivos são performance mesmo. Usando viewmodels você trafega apenas os dados necessários a view e em muitos casos já formatados. Usando a entidade sempre vai dados a mais. Eu costumo a colocar as viewmodels em projetos separados para casos onde a consulta a entidade é demorada eu crio uma view no BD e mapeio a viewmodel diretamente (usando nhibernate).